# Read only to datetime picker textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, datetimepicker

I'm using `Telerik DateTimePicker` .
Here is my code ,

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" ID="datePicker" Width="150px" >
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

[image]

I want to set `datePicker`'s `TextBox` to ReadOnly .

Comment: a lot better option is i\to use ajax claender extender...http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set [`EnableTyping`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/p_telerik_web_ui_raddatepicker_enabletyping.html) to false:

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" 
                       ID="datePicker" 
                       Width="150px" 
                       EnableTyping="false">
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use following:**

```
<radCln:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker1" runat="server">
        <DateInput ReadOnly="true"></DateInput>
</radCln:RadDatePicker>
```

**Referance:**

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/calendar/readonly-datepicker-textbox.aspx

**Demo:**

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datepicker/shareddatepicker/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

RadDateTimePicker does not support ReadOnly mode out of the box. But you can easily achieve ReadOnly behavior. For this purpose, handle and cancel ValueChanging event.
Please refer to the attached sample project.

for more details go to the following link

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/calendar-and-datetimepicker/datetimepicker-readonly-property.aspx

Answer (score 0):

both the above mentioned techniques give you the readonly behavior.

You can set the EnableTyping="false" like below:

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" ID="rdp" EnableTyping="false" />
```

or

You can set the DateInput to readonly like below:

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" ID="rdp">
    <DateInput ReadOnly="true"/>
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way how you can enable false from code behind:

```
RadDatePicker1.EnableTyping = false;
RadDatePicker1.DatePopupButton.Enabled = false;
```